Writing a backwards-compatible AppArmor profile
I am developing an application that I provide as a .deb package (via a PPA or for direct download and installation). Because this application uses user namespaces, it is blocked from working on Ubuntu 23.10+ and I want to include an AppArmor profile for it in the package as described in Ubuntu's blog post about this restriction.
The blog post presents this AppArmor profile:
abi <abi/4.0>,

include <tunables/global>

/opt/google/chrome/chrome flags=(default_allow) {
  userns,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  include if exists <local/opt.google.chrome.chrome>
}

If I adapt this to my application and install it as part of my package, this breaks AppArmor on older Ubuntu versions, because <abi/4.0> cannot be found or the flag default_allow is not defined.
How can I write an AppArmor profile that works on all current Ubuntu versions (at least 22.04 and 24.04) and enables default_allow and userns if the Ubuntu version is at least 23.10? I tried to find something conditional in man apparmor.d but didn't succeed except for include if exists, which doesn't seem like a solution.
I am looking for something that allows me to configure a profile depending on whether a file like <abi/4.0> exists or depending on the current Ubuntu or AppArmor version or whether userns is a valid rule or so.

Unfortunately there is not a way to do that with AppArmor currently. I have seen some people use tools like jinja2 to accomplish what you're looking for. This is an example from the ubuntu pro client: https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-pro-client/pull/2794/commits
